# Asp Gridview Edit columns issue : Checkbox does not update columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am fairly new to Asp.Net. I have been trying to Edit a column value in a gridview but upon checking one of the two checkboxes (Yes or No), it does not update anything.
Sharing Gridview code below :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#000000" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                              BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="6" DataKeyNames="film_data" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" ForeColor="White" 
                              GridLines="Vertical" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AllowSorting="True">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCC" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True">
                        <ControlStyle ForeColor="Blue" />
                        </asp:CommandField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="film_title" HeaderText="MOVIE TITLE" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="film_title" >
                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="film_release" HeaderText="RELEASE DATE" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="release_date" >
                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:CheckboxField DataField="Yes" HeaderText="YES" SortExpression="Yes" />
                        <asp:CheckboxField DataField="No" HeaderText="NO" SortExpression="No" />
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                   
                    <RowStyle  />
                </asp:GridView>
```

This is the GridView1_RowDataBound snippet from .cs file.

```
public void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Checking the RowType of the Row  
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
     ....
```

What am I missing here ? Upon clicking Edit, and the Yes or No checkboxes. nothing gets updated. There is no error either. Kindly assist.

Comment: If you are new to asp.net then don't learn that. Use MVC or MVC core instead.

Answer (score 0):

In Gridview change the commandfield and checkbox control like this in your code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Yes/No">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Literal ID="ltrchkboxVal" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "chkboxval").ToString() %>'></asp:Literal>
</ItemTemplate> 
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnchkboxval" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "chkboxval").ToString() %>'/>
<asp:CheckboxList ID="chkyesboxval" runat="server" Width="40">
<asp:ListItem> Yes</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem> No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckboxList >
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" CancelText="Cancel" ControlStyle-CssClass="small"
EditText="Optimise" HeaderText="Optimise" ShowEditButton="true" UpdateText="Apply" ItemStyle-Width="30px">                               
</asp:CommandField>
```

IN c# code

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
DivMessage.Visible = false;
GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
//Bind gridview       
}
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
string yesnoval = (GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("chkyesboxval") as CheckBoxList).SelectedItem.Value; 

// update new values and Bind gridview
}
protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
//Bind gridview
}
```

Add events for the gridview control

```
  onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
 onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing"
 onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
```